# Trying to write the text in the center of each PPTX slide with python-pptx package

Tags: alignment, python-pptx

I am using python-pptx to create a PPTX that will consist in writing 1 single word (extracted from a list, provided in the python script) just in the center of each slide;
My list consists in 10 words, as an example, and the Python script successfully manages to create 1 PPTX of 10 slides with a word of the list, with the requested font size, per slide;
so, this is not too bad, for a beginner like me;
But, I did not find a way to write this single word  in the center of each slide;

Here is the Python script :

```
# import required things 
from pptx import Presentation  
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt 
from pptx.enum.text import MSO_ANCHOR
from pptx.enum.text import PP_ALIGN
import random
import json

adjectifs = ["grand", "petit", "beau", "laid", "joli", "moche", "intelligent", "stupide", "gentil", "méchant"]

# Mélange la liste des adjectifs
random.shuffle(adjectifs)
  
# Creating Object 
ppt = Presentation()  

# Get bounding box of shapes
# bounding_box = slide.shapes.bounding_box

# To create blank slide layout 
# We have to use 6 as an argument 
# of slide_layouts   
blank_slide_layout = ppt.slide_layouts[6]  



# for slide in ppt.slides:
for adjectif in adjectifs:
  # Ajoute un adjectif aléatoire sur le slide
  # adjectif = random.choice(adjectifs)

  # Attaching slide obj to slide
  slide = ppt.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
  # For adjusting the  Margins in inches
  left = top = width = height = Inches(1)
  # creating textBox
  txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height)
  # creating textFrames
  tf = txBox.text_frame
  tf.text = adjectif
  paragraph = tf.paragraphs[0]
  paragraph.font.size = Pt(60)
  paragraph.font.bold = True
  paragraph.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.MIDDLE
  paragraph.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
  # tf.fit_text(font_family="Calibri", max_size=60, bold=True)

  # Center the Text Frame : all solutions below were unsuccessful
  # tf.x = slide.width / 2 - tf.width / 2
  # tf.y = slide.height / 2 - tf.height / 2
  # slide_width = slide.shape.width
  # slide_width = slide.shapes.width
  # slide_width = slide.dimensions.width
  # slide_width = slide.slide_area.width
  # slide_width = bounding_box.right - bounding_box.left
  # tf.left = slide_width / 2 - tf.width / 2
  # tf.top = slide.height / 2 - tf.height / 2

# save file 
ppt.save('50_Adjectifs.pptx') 

  

print("done")
```

I tried with those 2 commands :

```
  paragraph.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.MIDDLE
  paragraph.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
b
```

But, it seems that this is only useful to move the position of the text inside the text frame, but not to move the Text Frame itself in the Slide ...

Any ideas would be welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It works well when working out the size/placement of the textbox intially

```
from pptx import Presentation  
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt 
from pptx.enum.text import MSO_ANCHOR, PP_ALIGN
import random

adjectifs = ["grand", "petit", "beau", "laid", "joli", "moche", "intelligent", "stupide", "gentil", "méchant"]
random.shuffle(adjectifs)

ppt = Presentation()  
blank_slide_layout = ppt.slide_layouts[6]

slide_width = ppt.slide_width
slide_height = ppt.slide_height
margin = Inches(1)

for adjectif in adjectifs:
    slide = ppt.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
    left = margin
    top = margin
    width = slide_width - 2 * margin
    height = slide_height - 2 * margin

    txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height)
    tf = txBox.text_frame
    tf.margin_top = 0
    tf.margin_bottom = 0
    tf.margin_left = 0
    tf.margin_right = 0
    tf.text = adjectif
    paragraph = tf.paragraphs[0]
    paragraph.font.size = Pt(60)
    paragraph.font.bold = True
    paragraph.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
    for paragraph in tf.paragraphs:
        paragraph.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
        paragraph.space_before = Pt(0)
        paragraph.space_after = Pt(0)

    # Ensure vertical centering
    tf.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.MIDDLE

ppt.save('50_Adjectifs.pptx')
print("done")
```